# Set a particular question at top of my favorites

Tags: support, bookmarks

How do I set a particular question I am concerned about the most at top of all favorites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible within the UI.  The next best thing you can do is bookmark that specific favorite instead, so you can refer to it within your browser's ordering system.

Comment: with some effort it seems possible to maintain top position of particular question if one [picks ordering favorites by newest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=favorites&sort=newest "example"). All one needs to do is to re-favorite the desired question after adding newer favorites